# Newly published article does not load

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I have published a new article, which is in a published category and menu that contain other published articles.

The article, which is public, goes to a 404 error page. The url of the article is:

https://tesep.org.au/quick-pd-extinction-events-2

I am a bit puzzled by this as the other articles have no problem loading.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: I don't see any menu that would redirect me to "published" articles list. The article url above is not a proper slug. The question is - where the article is about to appear?

Comment: Sorry, I need to be clearer: the article is in "Uncategorised" along with several other articles. The url for these are the websitename/alias. Yet the alias as a url doesn't seem to work and it shows a 404 page. Compare: https://tesep.org.au/quick-pd-extinction-events, which works with https://tesep.org.au/critical-minerals-1-t4-22, which goes to a 404 page. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably need to create menu item for this article. No menu item means no working alias. Search your "menus" and check which menu contains alias 'quick-pd-extinction-events', it is likely set to single article menu item type. Use the same menu to create another item, because it looks it's not the main menu.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!